# Extended ascii characters in mySql with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, prepared-statement, extended-ascii

When inserting (or updating) a record in mysql using prepared statements and binding of values, I ran into a problem trying to insert the word `child’s` which contains the extended ascii character 145 (right single quotation mark). All data after the "d" is truncated. This is true for inserting any of the MS Word odd characters. My table is encoded as utf8_general_ci and I'm utf-8 all the way through in my code. The field is of type "text."

Of course I can escape them or do a `str_replace()` to remove them (which is what I am choosing to do), but I'd like to understand why I can't insert them directly since I always thought prepared statements handled this.

Sample insert code - incomplete, but it shows the essential

```
$q = "INSERT INTO mytable (userid, title, descr) VALUES (?,?,?)";

if (!($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($q))) {
    error_log("You have a problem...");
    return false;
}
/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $userid, $title, $descr);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->errno) {
    $e = new Exception;
    error_log("\r\nSql Error: " . $q . ' Sql error #: ' . $stmt->errno . ' - ' . $stmt->error . "\r\n" . $e->getTraceAsString());
    return false;
} else {
    $lastinsertedid = $this->mysqli->insert_id;

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
    return $lastinsertedid;
}
```

Comment: your using utf8 all the way through ?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be an issue, binding the param as a string should escape any quotes as needed.

Try this to see if you can see what the error is.

```
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($q);
    if (!is_object($stmt))
        error_log("You have a problem...");
        var_dump($this->mysqli);
    }
```

P.S. Don't forget `$stmt->close()` after `$stmt->execute()` as you will run into out of sync issues when attempting multiple prepared statements

I can offer some tips on syntax clean up too, take your updated question:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO mytable (userid, title, descr) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $this->mysql->prepare($q);

if (!is_object($stmt))
    error_log("You have a problem...");
    var_dump($this->mysqli);
}

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $userid, $title, $descr);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->errno) {
    $stmt->close(); // Still need to close here

    $e = new Exception;
    error_log("\r\nSql Error: " . $q . ' Sql error #: ' . $stmt->errno . ' - ' . $stmt->error . "\r\n" . $e->getTraceAsString());
    return false;
}

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();

return $this->mysqli->insert_id;
```

Comment: I've updated my post with the error checking code which follows. It does not throw any errors and inserts just fine... with the exception of truncating the string starting with the special character.

Comment: Ok so that eliminates any issue with the query you're sending. Odd, as a sloppy work around you could use `addslashes($title)` or even worse use `htmlentities($title)`. Wish I had something more iron-clad to recommend for you.

Comment: Do you only have this issue with TEXT fields?

Comment: I believe so. I saw the title field truncated as well on a different post.

Answer (score 0):

The *encoding* for `’` was not utf8.  That is the only problem.  Your code may be utf8 throughout, but the data was not.

The fact that `child’s` truncated after the `d` is the symptom non-utf8 bytes being fed into otherwise good code.

Find out what application or code is generating the `’`, either figure out what encoding it is generating or figure out whether it can be made to generate utf8.  In the former case, we need to change one setting, in the other case, no code change need be made.

`HEX('’')` is `E282AC` in utf8.

Comment: The data is from a text file. The str_replace option is working for the moment. I probably could have gone the route of converting the data line by line as the text file is read using `iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text);` or something like this. The problem now is going back and finding the data and testing this out as I have moved on. If I can, I will verify later. - Thanks.